# Responsive css grid with span

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create responsive css grid where I set some divs inside to take different amount of space, however when I resize they should align one per row. This is how it curently behaves except that those elements that I set to have `grid-column: span 2` leave empty space to the right of them. You can see the behavior in the snippet. Ultimately I need them to have same length on small spaces but I do not want to use media queries. Is it possible with CSS grid?

```css
* {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

html {
  background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #C62828, #BA68C8);
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 22px;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

code {
  margin: 1px 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px 1px 5px;
  font-family: monospace;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
}

p {
  margin: 25px 10px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.outlined {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.grid > * {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  /*margin: 10px;*/
  text-align: center;
}

.grid a {
    display: block;
}

.grid > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color ease 0.5s;
}


.grid {
    display: grid;
    /* grid-template-rows:100px 200px;
    grid-template-columns: 200px auto 150px; */
    grid-template-columns:  repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
   
    grid-gap: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;

}

.grid :nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid :nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: span 3;
}

.grid :nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid :nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <!-- Remove this line for offline development: -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid">
    <div>Grid item 1</div>
    <div>Grid item 2</div>
    <div>Grid item 3</div>
    <div>Grid item 4</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with media queries? They are an essential element .of adapting CSS-Grid to different viewports

Comment: It requires less code and since its already included with grid then why not use it?

Comment: This challenge would be interesting to solve with fluid layout (without media queries). We have a case in Dashboards were we can not rely on CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can try flexbox for this:

```css
* {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

html {
  background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #C62828, #BA68C8);
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 22px;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}


.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.grid>* {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-basis:0;
  flex-grow:2;
  min-width:300px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* to keep only two per line*/
.grid:before {
 content:"";
 flex-basis:100%;
}
/**/

/* make the first two before the pseudo element*/
.grid *:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  order:-1;
}
/* */

/* 2 and 4 will grow more */
.grid *:nth-child(even) {
  flex-grow:3
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>Grid item 1</div>
  <div>Grid item 2</div>
  <div>Grid item 3</div>
  <div>Grid item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So its not really possible with grid?

Comment: @AlexT without media query I don't think so